# Where is the correct place to put vendor files in Cakephp 2.X?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, vendor

I've taken over an old CakePHP 2.X website and have no prior experience with CakePHP so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I was looking at making some changes to some vendor files and noticed that we appear to have multiple copies of various files (which are, for the most part, identical) in 2 different places:

- app/webroot/api/vendor/API/lib/
- vendors/API/lib/

Additionally I noticed there are several other vendor directories in various other places.

I am using `App::import('Vendor', 'example', array('file' => 'API/lib/example.php'));` to load the scripts in question.

Could someone please explain to me what the best practices are regarding file structure relating to vendor files? Additionally, am I safe to delete the duplicate copy of all the files? How does CakePHP know which copy to load?

Edit:

I have come to the conclusion that the files are being loaded from `vendors/API/lib/` rather than `app/webroot/api/vendor/API/lib/`, is it possible that the files in the latter location are redundant? I cannot seem to find any references to them.

Comment: Use in Vendor folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back a few years later with a little more experience, I feel like I can answer this question better and hopefully help others.

There are only 2 vendor folders in a standard CakePHP 2.0 implementation:
`/vendors` and `/app/Vendor` (Note the difference in case and plurality). The one I found in /app/webroot and any other vendor folders you may find are not associated with cakePHP.

The reason CakePHP has 2 different vendor folders is because you are able to run 2 (or more) CakePHP apps on one copy of the library by creating a second app folder. The `/vendors` folder is for vendors that are common between all these apps and the `/app/Vendor` folder is for vendors of that specific app.

I could not find any best practice information on which one to use by default but I suggest you pick one and stick with it unless you anticipate adding a second app to the installation in the future.

By using only these 2 folders for vendors you can ensure that standard CakePHP helper methods such as "App::import" and "App::uses" are able to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Well as Sudhir has commented you, there is a folder in your app project which is called Vendor. I would recommend you to put  it there.
app > Vendor

For example, I have created a folder called Csv for generating my own csv files through a Shell which is launching them. It is located inside app > Vendor > Csv

For importing this to my projects, I did the next for being able to use it:

```
     <?php

      include('GenericShell.php');
      require_once(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Csv' . DS . 
      'CsvGenerator.php');

     class CsvPatientsShell extends GenericShell {
```

That's one only example with PHP.

One other one would be, if in this case you have a Component which is called component.php and you want to import it to a Controller which you use frequently inside your project :

Component would be located into 
              Controller > Component > Namecomponent.php

The next thing you would have to do would be to do the import likewise inside your controller:
Let's say your controller's name is NameController.php and is located inside the Controller folder. 
Controller > NameController.php

```
  public function main_function() {

    App::import('Component', 'Namecomponent');
    $NameComponent = new NameComponent();

    $this->layout = null;
    $this->autoLayout = false;
    die();
}
```

That would be a more correct way to do it with CakePhp but both mentioned are legit I'd say.
I hope that will help you somehow.